# How to call subclass methods when subclass objects are stored in superclass array?

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance, subclass, superclass

```
{
    Ship ships = new Ship();
    CargoShip cargoShips = new CargoShip();
    CruiseShip cruiseShips = new CruiseShip();

    Ship[] allShips = {ships, cargoShips, cruiseShips};

    allShips[0].setShipName("Boom");
    allShips[0].setYearBuilt("1900");
    allShips[1].setShipName("Bang");
    allShips[1].setCargoCapaicty(200);
    allShips[2].setShipName("Bam");
    allShips[2].setMaxPassengers(500);


    for (int i = 0; i < allShips.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(allShips[i]);
    }
}
```

So the Ship class is the super class while CargoShip and CruiseShip both extend the Ship class. I've stored the 3 objects into a Ship array. setCargoCapacity and setMaxPassengers are methods that only appear in the subclasses. For some reason I cannot access them. I can't figure out how to make it so that I can also access the subclass methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could initialize your objects *before* storing them in the array:

```
Ship ships = new Ship();
ships.setShipName("Boom");
ships.setYearBuilt("1900");

CargoShip cargoShips = new CargoShip();
cargoShips.setShipName("Bang");
cargoShips.setCargoCapaicty(200);

CruiseShip cruiseShips = new CruiseShip();
cruiseShips.setShipName("Bam");
cruiseShips.setMaxPassengers(500);

Ship[] allShips = {ships, cargoShips, cruiseShips};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't call `setCargoCapacity` of a `Ship` you picked out of a `Ship[]` because that ship might not be a `CargoShip`. You must either provide some method in the `Ship` class (and therefore for all Ships) that does what you need it to do, or check whether `ship instanceof CargoShip`, and if so you can cast it (`CargoShip cargoShip = (CargoShip)ship`) and call the `setCargoCapacity` of that.

Answer (score 0):

You cant do it. In java reference variables have two types: reference type and actual object type. So, when you write something like `Object o = "12345"`, `o` has type `Object` (not `String`), and you cant work with `o` like with string without typecasting: `o = ((String)o).substring(1);`.

In your case all references in your array `allShips` have type `Ship`. If you know that actual type of some array element is a `Ship` subclass, you can cast actual type like above. But it's a bad practice and shouldn't be used in real world.

Answer (score 0):

```
allShips[0].setShipName("Boom");
allShips[0].setYearBuilt("1900");
allShips[1].setShipName("Bang");
((CargoShip)allShips[1]).setCargoCapaicty(200);
allShips[2].setShipName("Bam");
((CruiseShip)allShips[2]).setMaxPassengers(500);
```

try this. It will work.